# Twilio filter if the recording source is recordverb

Tags: php, twilio-php

I need to filter the recording list and I just only need to get the record verb for making my voicemails but the conference source is not filtered

```
$temp_arr = array();

foreach ($client->account->recordings->getIterator(0, 50, array('CallSid' => 'call sid here' , 'Source' => 'Recordverb')) as $recording){
    $recording_uri = "https://api.twilio.com".$recording->uri;
    $arr = array(
        'rec' => $recording_uri,
    );
    array_push($temp_arr, $arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to filter recordings based upon `Conference` or `RecordVerb`?

`Source` [from the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-properties):

> The type of call that created this recording. Possible values are
>   RecordVerb, DialVerb, Conference, OutboundAPI, Trunking.

You also have this `'Source' => 'Recordverb'` where you could just have a typo with the lowercase 'v'.

Comment: yes, Ive already done that changing that to capital V but still its not filtering all the recording, I just need to filter the RecordVerb

Answer (score 0):

I am late to respond but maybe someone else will get benefit from this. You may simply use this code for getting RecoredVerb

```
$recordings = $twilio->recordings->read([], 200);
foreach ($recordings as $record) {          
    if($record->source == 'RecordVerb'){
        $record_sid= $record->sid;
    }else if($record->source == 'DialVerb'){
    }else {
    }

}
```

You can do your desired work inside the conditions.